# Team freezes various people in apartment building

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

There was a show or movie that I saw quite some time ago (like 2001, maybe). I think it was on the Sci-Fi channel but not 100% sure.

These people there had invented this technology that was like a flash of light and it would freeze people in their tracks on whatever they were doing. All I remember from the scene was a SWAT team or something going around in an apartment building with this technology and would flash it and stop people in their motion. They knocked down one room's door and froze a couple fighting about the husband cheating on her.

Another scene showed this couple having sex in another room and the SWAT team knocked down the door and froze them too and shot the man in the head, and it went on. They would collect information or something from their heads when they would freeze the people with the flash technology.

I know this is vague and lacks detail but it's honestly all I can remember.  I would greatly appreciate it if anyone knows what movie\tv show I may be talking about... it's been bugging me for a long time!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds very much like a scene in [Minority Report](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/) in which the precrime police deploy "spiders" to ID the building's inhabitants in their search for John Anderton. No one gets frozen, but the implication is that the residents of the buildings are so familiar with the procedure that they stop what they're doing in order to be scanned. This includes an arguing couple who appear to freeze mid-fight and then resume fighting after being scanned.

[Note: the clip below is from later in the scene I described, and does not show the arguing couple, etc.]

Comment: Minority Report is exactly what his description reminded me of, but like you say nobody got frozen, instead people simply needed to cooperate to get the search done.

Answer (score 0):

[Looker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looker) is my long-shot guess

The bad guys use an optical flash weapon that "freezes" people in place, but I do not remember anything about SWAT teams or getting something out of someones head.